# Error while editing nested form, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm using nested form and want to add 'edit option' option like

```
 = link_to 'Edit', edit_user_service_exp_path(@service_exp.user, @service_exp)
```

But it gives error 'no route match'.
all other functionality works perfectly e.g.

```
= link_to 'Delete', [@service_exp.user, @service_exp], :confirm => 'Are you sure?',  :method => :delete
```

Only error for edit link.
Here is edit action:

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @service_exp = @user.service_exps.find(params[:id])
  render :layout => false
end
```

Comment: Please add your routes for this resource.

Comment: your routes should look like: resources :users do resources :service_exps end

Comment: Matt, Mattherick I already added routes for this and all works perfectly like delete, create but problem on edit case